# Fetching images from two different servers

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-2.0

Can anyone please tell me the procedure to bring two images from different servers in Silverlight 2?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "bring two images"? Do you mean download them into the client application to work with them, put them on the screen, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

If You have the url u can just set it to image controls.

img1.Source=new BitmapImage(new Uri(your_url_for_the_iamge)); //img1 is your image control

If you want to download them and then use you need to use WebClient class and one clientaccesspolicy.xml file should be present in the server from where you are donwloading the images and that xml file should grant you access to where your Silverlight application is.

Comment: I'm guessing that faisal71 was hoping to actually WebClient the images in, so you're totally right here: the client access policy for x-domain requests would need to be in place in the 3rd party server(s).